# How do I update the SVN commit message log?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A co-worker has made several changes to old commit messages. He changed the issue that was referenced in them. My local working copy does not seem to pick up on these changes and so I cannot search for all commits of that issue.

If I click "edit log message" on one of the commits the updated message is shown but svn log seems to show a cached version.

How do I clear that cache and get the latest version of all messages?

Note: Even a new checkout of the repository still uses the old messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using, then:

TortoiseSVN, then Settings -> Log Caching -> Cached Repositories

here delete in list all entries.